# How to make a rails template forcefully not run bundle install after rails new is finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, generator, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating a Rails Template with stuff I want to do, including setting up a RVM gemset and installing gems inside it. I can do this just fine programmatically, but I also would like to disable the default `bundle install` rails runs after you initiate a new project with `rails new`. I can easily run `rails new app -m mytemplate.rb --skip-bundle` or add `--skip-bundle` to `~/.railsrc`. But I would prefer a lot more if I could just add this to my template and never have to remember again about `.railsrc` or any other config option.

Can I do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

`def run_bundle ; end`

at the end of the template file to overwrite the run_bundle method.